# Solving logistic population model with euler

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a function for population growth.

$$\frac{dp}{dt} = a \cdot p(t)-b \cdot p(t)^2,\: p(0) = p_0$$

Now I want to use the Euler method to approximate this model.
I already have an Euler method in Python which is working.
This Euler method has 4 parameters.
Euler(function $f$, initialcondition $p_0$, stepsize $t$, steps $n$).

But I don't understand what will the function $f$ will be in this case.
$a$ and $b$ are constants but I don't understand what $p(t)$ is and how I can create the function $f$ with this information.

Comment: Euler's method is a numerical method and will not produce the function. This equation is separable and you can find a closed form solution. The function for Euler's is $ap - bp^2$, so you need $a$ and $b$ to use a numerical method.

Comment: I understand what Euler´s method is. But I don´t understand how I can use it to solve my problem. For example I have p(0)=1 as initial condition. And I am using the ap-bp^2 function. What is p?

Comment: $p$ is $f$. Change $p$ to $f$ if you'd like. $f = ap -bp^2$. Why is this confusing? You have the constants, the initial condition and $f$, now use in the numerical algorithm.

Comment: I don´t know but I still don´t understand what the p means in ap-bp^2. For example normally I used python this to create my f. def f(x,y): return x + y. But how will I create the function in my case? def f(x,y): return a*x-b*y^2 ?

Comment: No, you only have a function of one variable instead of two. How about you do Euler's manually before getting caught up with a program?

Answer (score 1):

My limited skills are more in the c++/Mathematica realm, and so I made this working code in Mathematica for you using only a basic loop. Sometimes an example is worth a thousand words, and I am hoping your education will make it clear what is going on here:

```
a = .1;                  (* your a parameter *)
b = .001;                (* your b parameter *)
x = 1;                   (* starting x value *)
p = 1;                   (* starting p value *)
t = 1;                   (* step size t *)
f[p_] := a*p - b*p^2;    (* your function *)

eulertable = {};         (* build table (x, p). n steps in loop *)

For[n = 1, n <= 100, n++,
    AppendTo[eulertable, {x, p}];
    p = p + t*f[p];
     x = x + t;
   ]

ListPlot[eulertable, AxesLabel -> {"x", "p"}] (* output as data plot *)
```

The output as a plot of the data (x, p) is:

[image: output of data as a plot]

I hope this is helpful, for I can do no better, and c++ code would not look much different, just slightly different syntax style and I would not know how to plot in console.